# Docked CMD terminal window in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, cmd

I thought this one was easy to google, but I was wrong.

I just want a regular cmd prompt terminal window as a docked window inside Visual Studio, much like the Package Manager console. But I can't seem to find a way.

Is it possible?

Comment: Are you asking for just the output of the command application to appear inside the Visual Studio IDE and not the actual window itself?

Answer (score 0):

Well there's [Open Command Line](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4e84e2cf-2d6b-472a-b1e2-b84932511379) as a VS extension, but sadly it doesn't dock the command prompt, so it's only halfway there for you.

Answer (score -1):

You can search for a real console window that you launch with `system` or `CreateProcess` via this code snippet:

```
HWND hCmd = ::FindWindow(_T("ConsoleWindowClass"), _T("aa")); // "aa" is the name/title of the window
if (hCmd != NULL) {
    // Set new parent
    // hParent is the handle to the new parent window (a dockable window)
    ::SetParent(hCmd, hParent); 
    // TODO: set child's window style to your liking...
}
```